# The real roots of an equation $f(x) = 0, f'(x) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that, if $f(x) = x^2(1-x)^2$, then the roots of the equation $f''(x) = 0$ are distinct, and lie between 0 and 1.

Prove that the corresponding result for the equation $g'''(x) = 0$, where $g(x) = x^3(1-x)^3$

Comment: Are you sure that *Algebra - precalculus* tag is relevant ?

Comment: This is not a site for us to do your homework, show us what you tried yourself first. Then we can guide you further.

Comment: $f$ has roots of order $2$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$. Then its derivative also has roots at $x=0$ and $x=1$. By Rolle's theorem, there is $y\in(0,1)$ where $f'(y)=0$. By Rolle's theorem again, there are roots of $f''$ in $(0,y)$ and in $(y,1)$.

Comment: @soer9606 It looks like they did get answers to their question. So, you are wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm wrong, rather some people disagree with me, and that is fine. However I do believe that is is bad practice to just help someone without them helping themselves

Comment: @soer9606 But you are wrong. Those who are wrong never think that they are while they are wrong, only after they realize that they are they can see that they were.

Comment: @egorovik i see your point, but math.stackexchange has had quite a bit of discussion on this point, and I'm just following the general consensus. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = x^2(1-x)^2 $

Using chain rule ,

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{d(x^2)}{dx}(1-x^2) + \dfrac{d(1-x)^2}{dx}x^2 $$

$$f'(x) = 2x(2x^2 -3x+1)$$

Again differentiating it ,

$$ f''(x) = \dfrac{d(2x)}{dx}(2x^2 -3x+1) + \dfrac{d(2x^2 -3x+1)}{dx}2x $$ $$f''(x) = 2 (6x^2-6x+1)$$

So $f''(x) = 0 \implies 6x^2-6x+1=0 \implies x= \dfrac12 \pm \dfrac {1}{2\sqrt3}$

Comment: It is supposed to be $x^2(1-x)^2$ and not $x^2(x-1)^2$

Comment: @soer9606 Luckily, we have that $(-1)^2=1$.

Comment: @Botond Yeah, sorry, you are right

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = x^2(1-x)^2=x^2(1-2x+x^2)=x^2-2x^3+x^4$$

$$f'(x) = 2x-6x^2+4x^3$$

$$f''(x)=2-12x+12x^2=2(6x^2-6x+1)$$

$$f''(x)=0 \implies x=1/2 \pm \sqrt 3 /6$$

Thus the roots are strictly between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=z+1/2$ to get $$g(z)=(z+1/2)^2(1-z-1/2)^2=(z+1/2)^2(z-1/2)^2.$$  Clearly $g$ is an even function of degree $4$ with two minima at $z=\pm1/2$ and a maximum at $z=0$. Hence there exist exactly two inflection points, one between $-1/2$ and $0$, the other between $0$ and $1/2$, where $g''$ vanishes. From here $f''$ vanishes twice between $0$ and $1$.